# How can i find out when onDraw has finished?

Tags: android, view

how can I find out when onDraw of a View has finished?

Thanks!

Comment: What is it you are trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what you're ultimately trying to achieve, but if you need to run some logic once drawing has been completed in an `Activity`, then you can call `View.post(Runnable)` and put your logic inside there. `onDraw` would have likely taken place once the code in your `Runnable` has been reached since it put that `Runnable` on the message queue.

Answer (score 2):

Place a boolean member in your View class and set it to true when onDraw is called (If you simply want to be able to test that a View has drawn).

Or if you want some sort of post-draw "event" call to execute a new thread- just put it at the end of onDraw.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion how it could be done:

```
public class FVRTraceAbleListView extends ListView {

ListViewListener listener;


public interface ListViewListener {
    void onPostDraw();
}

public FVRTraceAbleListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public FVRTraceAbleListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public FVRTraceAbleListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public FVRTraceAbleListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}


public void setListener(ListViewListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);


    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onPostDraw();
    }
}
```

}